# want to create a histogram with two bars for two different year

Tags: r

i two datasets

df2010:

| type | Count |
| --- | --- |
| hate | 20'000 |
| drug | 15'600 |
| rape | 30'000 |
| murder | 32'000 |
| robbery | 45'700 |
| theft | 65'000 |

df2020:

| type | Count |
| --- | --- |
| hate | 42'000 |
| rape | 55'000 |
| murder | 16'000 |
| burglary | 11'800 |
| theft | 87'000 |

I did this in r:

```
# 2010
ggplot(df2010, aes(x = type, y = Count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") +
  xlab("Type") +
  ylab("Count") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Crime in 2010") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))


# 2020
ggplot(crime_type_2020, aes(x = type, y = Count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") +
  xlab("Type") +
  ylab("Count") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Crime in 2020") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

But I want this in one graphic whichh shows for every type two bars, one for 2012 and one for 2017. and all types thhat not occur in one year also show thhe name in the x axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help make a plot with data from both years, we can start by combining the two data frames:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- bind_rows('2010' = df2010, '2020' = df2020, .id = 'Year')
df

#>    Year    type Count
#> 1  2010    hate 20000
#> 2  2010    drug 15600
#> 3  2010    rape 30000
#> 4  2010  murder 32000
#> 5  2010 robbery 45700
#> 6  2010   theft 65000
#> 7  2020    hate 42000
#> 8  2020    drug 55000
#> 9  2020    rape 16000
#> 10 2020  murder 11800
#> 11 2020   theft 87000
```

Now you can map the year to the `fill` aesthetic in your plot, and get a column for each year. I labeled the years by the data frame names as I couldn't tell which was the 2012 or 2017 data.

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = type,
             y = Count,
             fill = Year)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single')) +
  labs(x = 'Type',
       y = 'Count',
       title = 'Distribution of Crime') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: but, how can I be sure, that always 2010 cames before 2020 in the graphic, on my graphic sometimes two blues are next to each other